# Clean up directory in Linux

Tags: bash

I have a linux directory which has many files about 64 k files basically all log files

Every time a job runs it creates about 9 log files, 5 are text files and 4 are bin files and all     these log files reside in the directory mentioned in Step1 .... base file names are same for those 9     files . So there are ~7000 base file names constituting a total of ~64000 total files

So my task is to cleanup the directory by moving the bin files to another directory but keep the     latest bin file in the same directory .

So the files names are like this:

```
DM_D_COVERAGE.log.0.bin
DM_D_COVERAGE.log.1.bin
DM_D_COVERAGE.log.2.bin
DM_D_COVERAGE.log.3.bin
```

They all have different last modified date.

Let me know in the comments if you need more information.

Comment: How can you detect the "latest" bin file? Is `DM_D_COVERAGE` constant across all the files?

Comment: what did you already try?

Comment: So every job create 9 log files :- 5 Text files and 4 .bin files. The base name for these log files are same. so in the above example  DM_D_COVERAGE.log is the base file. So far my approach was to capture all the .log file names in an array . Then using that array create another array which will have the hard coded names the base file name . 0.bin , .1.bin etc . Now I need to look in the log directory for the file names in Array 2 to determine their last modified date.Once I have the last modified date for all files , I can keep the latest .bin file and move the rest to another directory.

Comment: Haven't got any replies since yesterday. What could be the issue ?\

Answer (score 2):

`logrotate` is the tool for the job.  See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/.

Comment: These are not Linux log files, these are files created by another tool that's installed on Linux.